# Assign function type to a pointer in ghidra

Tags: ghidra

In the project I'm currently working on, I have found the following obfuscated access to functions in various libraries. In the following example, libdl is referenced.

```
  if (libdl_string_literal[8] != '\0') {
    magicDecodingFunction(0x86817231,0x86817231,0x11300316,libdl_string_literal,8,0xecd);
    libdl_string_literal[8] = '\0';
  }
  libdl = (void *)dlopen(libdl_string_literal,1);
  if (fun_libdl_dlopen_string_literal[6] != '\0') {
    magicDecodingFunction(0x86817231,0x86817231,0x11300316,fun_libdl_dlopen_string_literal,6,0xed6);
    fun_libdl_dlopen_string_literal[6] = '\0';
  }
  fun_libdl_dlopen = (void *)dlsym(libdl,fun_libdl_dlopen_string_literal);
```

`libdl`, `libdl_string_literal`, `fun_libdl_dlopen` are globals here.

After this bit runs, I am certain that `fun_libdl_dlopen` is always a reference to a function `void* dlopen(char* filename, int flags)`. How do I tell ghidra that the variable has that function signature?

For reference, I'm using ghidra 10.2 without any additional extensions.

Comment: Self comment: the entire initializer function is littered with such calls to libc, and libdl recreating the function table.

Comment: Do you have a function definition for dlopen in your data type manager?